# Function that multiplies the return of other functions then divides by 144

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if i have the correct syntax. I want a function to multiply the return of two other functions and then divide the result.
I have included the script below. Check out the third function calculateSquareFeet. I am referring to the var theSquareFeet.

```
//Set up an associative array
 //The keys represent the size of the plants
 //The values represent the square inches required per plant 
 var square_inches = new Array();
 square_inches ["seeds"]=16;
 square_inches ["seedlings"]=16;
 square_inches ["juveniles"]=64;
 square_inches ["adult"]=144;


 //Set up an associative array 
 //The keys represent the number of plants
 //The value represents the the number
 //We use this this array when the user selects a number from the forms first select box
 var num_plant= new Array();
    num_plant ["none"] = 0;
    num_plant [1] = 1;
    num_plant [2] = 2;
    num_plant [3] = 3;
    num_plant [4] = 4;
    num_plant [5] = 5;
    num_plant [6] = 6;
    num_plant [7] = 7;
    num_plant [8] = 8;
    num_plant [9] = 9;
    num_plant [10] = 10;
    num_plant [11] = 11;
    num_plant [12] = 12;
    num_plant [13] = 13;
    num_plant [14] = 14;
    num_plant [15] = 15;
    num_plant [16] = 16;
    num_plant [17] = 17;
    num_plant [18] = 18;
    num_plant [19] = 19;
    num_plant [20] = 20;
    num_plant [21] = 21;
    num_plant [22] = 22;
    num_plant [23] = 23;
    num_plant [24] = 24;
    num_plant [25] = 25;

var type_grow = new Array();
    type_grow [select] =0;
    type_grow [trad] =15;
    type_grow [hydro] =21;
    type_grow [undec] =0;



//This function finds the number of plants based on the 
//drop down selection
function getNumberOfPlants()
{
    var userNumberChoice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="sqfoot"
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="plantNumber"
     var selectedPlantNum = theForm.elements["plantNumber"];

    //set userNumberChoice equal to value user chose
    //For example num_plant[5.value] would be equal to 5
    userNumberChoice = num_plant[selectedPlantNum.value];

    //finally we return userNumberChoice
    return userNumberChoice;
}




// This function finds a number that represents square inches
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getSquareInches()
{  
    var thePlantSize=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="sqfoot"
    var theForm = document.forms["sqfoot"];
    //Get a reference to the plant size the user Chooses name=selectedPlant":
    var selectedPlant = theForm.elements["plantType"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedPlant.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPlant.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedPlant[i].checked)
        {
            //we set thePlantSize to the value of the selected radio button
            //i.e. if the user choose Juvenile we set it to 32
            //by using the square_inches array
            //We get the selected Items value
            //For example square_inches["Juvenile".value]"
            thePlantSize = square_inches[selectedPlant[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return thePlantSize
    return thePlantSize;
}

function calculateSquareFeet()
{
    /* Here we get the square feet by multiplying getNumberOfPlants() x getSquareInches() then divide by 144, the square inches in a square foot  */
    var theSquareFeet = (getNumberOfPlants() * getSquareInches()) / 144; 

        return theSquareFeet;
}
```

Comment: so whats wrong?..its perfectly fine

Comment: You *really* need to consider using a loop to build `num_plant`.

Comment: @Pilot - Look at the code.  Too many to list in my 550 characters.  It won't even parse because of the whacked keys in type_grow.

The code is currently a bunch of spaghetti that needs 30 minutes before anyone can even start answering a question.

Comment: @JohnGreen I think w/o looking at code you should focus on question title **Javascript function that multiplies the return of other functions then divides by 144**

Comment: @Pilot - The code is the context, and the context is broken badly.

Comment: No, your code has incorrect syntax. Associative arrays don't exist in JavaScript. If you're coming from PHP, the equivalent type would be an object. Also, you won't reliably get integers from your sq ft function, so you will probably want to round it. Also, as @meagar suggested, you should make use of a loop to generate some of that data.

Comment: Sorry to have blasted you with the spaghetti. Very new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the third function is correct.

although I would reduce it to:

```
function calculateSquareFeet(){
  return getNumberOfPlants() * getSquareInches() / 144; 
}
```

But that does not make what you wrote incorrect.
theSquareFeet is not needed. 
Technically it wastes a bit of ram and a few CPU cycles.
But it is not wrong.

Comment: Yes it does answer my question. And the tip about the code reduction was appreciated.

Comment: If I knew how to I would.

Comment: sorry. Just realized all I need to do is click the check mark.

Comment: FYI: You get 2 points for choosing an answer and I get 10 points because you chose mine. Thank you.  Now lets both go back in and delete these comments as they will do no good for anyone else that reads this thread later. To do that, hover over a comment that you wrote, a gray circle with an "X" in it appears after the comment. Click on the circle and the comment goes away. I will come back an remove this comment after I see that you have had the chance to prune your. Best, T.

Answer (score 0):

You have already made the correct function that you desire, however as far as syntax you have made a mistake constructing the `type_grow` array

It should be:

```
var type_grow = new Array();
    type_grow ["select"] =0;
    type_grow ["trad"] =15;
    type_grow ["hydro"] =21;
    type_grow ["undec"] =0;
```

For further reading on associative arrays in javascript, this site has a good explaination: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte go in to jsfiddle or w3schools and test it, you certainly can assign those values to those keys

Comment: I perhaps should have said you shouldn't assign those keys to an array. You're no longer using `Array` as an array in the strict sense. You are essentially using it as an object. Sure, it works, but try to get the length of that "associative array" and you'll find that it is 0, even though you have four items there.

Comment: It is a correct javascript way to assign an associative array - it will fail with `cannot set property of undefined` if you do not initialise it with `new Array()` or `[]` first. The OP has already used some in his code, so should know how to reference the items within (as he does with the `square_inches` array.)

Comment: Of course if you want, you can also assign it with `new Object()`, but I think it is (probably) more common that people use `new Array()` simply because, while an object, it's function is as an associative array (in this case) and thus adds clarity to the code in that it is obvious at a glance what the function of this Object is